# How to create a custom "Document Property"?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I create a "Document Property" like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4H4j.png) but with my own text?

[image]

Comment: Googled "word document property" and got http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-document-HA010047524.aspx, and http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/add-property-information-to-a-document-HA010163766.aspx#BM1 from MS's office.microsoft.com -- Did you try any of this?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes actually, didn't find what I was looking for. I created the new Document Properties like it said but they're not available under Quick Parts after I do.

Comment: 1) You should tell us what you've tried already, and what the results were, we are not mind reader. :)  2) It's in the second link.. It even uses the "Company Address" as the example... Did you not see that, or did it not work for you? If it didn't work, what didn't work about it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, because "Company Address" is a *built-in* document property, which is how I created it in the first place. I didn't think it was worth mentioning because it doesn't allow me to use my *own text* which was the whole point of the question. Alexandre managed to figure out what I was talking about.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. Again we're not mind readers, so in the future please include exactly what you've tried, and what the results were.  Keeps us from having to "figure out" what you're actually asking, and asking you about things you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean content control. Go to Word options, and  in Customize Ribbon, activate the Developer tab in the right list.
Then, get back to the doc and open the Developer tab.

In the Controls group, click Plain Text Content Control. 
This adds the text input box. If you want to give it a name like the screenshot, turn on Design Mode, select the box and then Properties.

There you can edit its title and other stuff.

Comment: These won't be added under Quick Parts like the other properties, either. The properties either have to be built-ins, cover page properties, or defined as server meta properties for that.